# how to referece viewmodel properties from separaete class method

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, mvvm

I am a newbie.
I am trying to build a WPF application using MVVM. So far I have bound my view model properties to my view. Pretty clean and nice. No code behind.

My business logic is to start one or several batch process based on user input. The background process will in turn update the status on the view’s processbar and/or textblock.

My question is 
What is the most MVVM way to do this?
Shall I put the batch processing code directly in my viewmodel class? If yes my viewmodel class looks big (thousands of lines)

Or shall I make a separate class in BusinessLogic folder (layer) to house the batch logic? If so how can I reference the viewmodel (UI) properties for input/output in the business logic class? Just pass those properties into the business logic class/method as parameters? and if so it looks like I have to pass a lot of properties as parameters. Is this the common MVVM way?

Please guide me in the right direction.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The processing logic should not go in the view-model, but the view-model will "know" how to kick off the process, probably by instantiating some component and calling a method on it, passing any parameters that the user specified in the UI.

That component that does the processing can emit status events (messages, percent complete, or both). The view-model can subscribe to these events (and unsubscribe when processing is complete), and update its properties accordingly.

For example, you may have a view-model property like this:

```
public string StatusMessage
 {
    get { return _statusMessage; }
    set 
    {
        _statusMessage = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("StatusMessage"); // you need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged
    }
}
```

Your component that does the processing may emit an event at 10% completion intervals and another event in the case of an error. You can subscribe to these events in the view-model and set the StatusMessage property to things like "Processing - 30% complete" or "Processing failed due to timeout."